# creating Low Weighted website with blog feature from client side without WordPress or other CMS

Tags: content-management-system, blogs

I am Building a website and i want to add a menu as Blog I want to know that if there is any new advanced way to create blog Post for client to update blogs from their end without using WordPress or any other CMS because I want to keep my website weight as low as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Architecture of a minimal blog/CMS would consist of:

- client-side code which you can serve off a storage (e.g. AWS S3)
- authentication for signing-up and signing-in users (through 3rd party authentication using oAuth, like Google, facebook, github etc)
- Server-side code to process (or run workflow) for the blog-posts (AWS
  Lambda or google functions)
- Database to store the content (any noSQL DB like MongoDB or DynamoDB etc.)

This way, you'll be able to keep things simple, fast and optimized - and very low cost too !!